# In Julia, Find the maximum for each position of a set of arrays

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an array like this

```
a = [ rand(1:20,3)  for i in 1:2,j in 1:3]
2×3 Array{Array{Int64,1},2}:
2×3 Array{Array{Int64,1},2}:
 [8, 13, 1]   [12, 4, 9]  [13, 18, 7]
 [3, 19, 20]  [8, 3, 11]  [10, 9, 12]
```

I would like that for each row, obtain an array 1 x 3 with maximum in each position along the row. For example, in the example above:

```
[13,18,9]
[10,19,20]
```

(this question was also asked on another platform: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/find-the-maximum-for-each-position-of-a-set-of-arrays/62155/3 )

Comment: I'd just like to add that you may benefit from refactoring your code. These types of data structures usually come from MATLAB where users like to pack everything into cells of arrays of cells of arrays, ad infinitum. This is not good for performance in general, so if you could simplify your code to avoid nesting of structures you could experience major speedups without intermediate memory allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers from the linked Discourse thread:

```
julia> a = [  [[8, 13, 1]]   [[12, 4, 9]]  [[13, 18, 7]]
        [[3, 19, 20]]  [[8, 3, 11]]  [[10, 9, 12]]  ];  # as in question

julia> res1 = [max.(row...) for row in eachrow(a)]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [13, 18, 9]
 [10, 19, 20]

julia> res1 == [vec(maximum(reduce(hcat, row), dims=2)) for row in eachrow(a)]
true

julia> using TensorCast

julia> res1 == @reduce res[i][k] := maximum(j) a[i,j][k]
true
```

Compare:

```
julia> res2 = collect.(eachrow(maximum.(a)))
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [13, 12, 18]
 [20, 11, 12]

julia> res2 == [maximum.(b) for b in eachrow(a)]
true

julia> res2 == @reduce res[i][j] := maximum(k) a[i,j][k]
true
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right you can just vectorize over `maximum`:

```
julia> a = [ rand(1:20,3)  for i in 1:2,j in 1:3]
2×3 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [13, 10, 10]  [14, 8, 9]    [15, 8, 5]
 [18, 18, 7]   [19, 10, 17]  [17, 8, 7]

julia> maximum.(a)
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 13  14  15
 18  19  17
```

Should you want to have a vector of rows use `collect` combined with `eachrow`:

```
julia> collect(eachrow(maximum.(a)))
2-element Vector{SubArray{Int64, 1, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, true}}:
 [13, 14, 15]
 [18, 19, 17]
```